# TypeORM: One-To-One relation doesn't create foreign key for subtable

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have two entities

Users:

```js
@Entity()
export class Users {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  user_id: number;

  @OneToOne(_ => UserContacts, contact => contact.user_id)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'contact_id' })
  contacts: UserContacts
}
```

```js
@Entity()
export class UserContacts {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  contact_id: number;

  @OneToOne(_ => Users, users => users.contacts)
  user_id: Users;
}
```

But in PostgreSQL after saving I have:

user_contacts table:

```
 contact_id | user_id
------------+---------
          6 |
```

users table:

```
 user_id | contact_id
---------+------------
       7 |          6
```

I suppose in user_contacts table in user_id column should be 7

I just learn TypeORM so I don't create any architecture

I have two functions for creating contacts and users

My save flow:

```js
export function createUser(contacts?: UserContacts): Users {
  const user = new Users();
  user.firstName = faker.name.firstName();
  user.lastName = faker.name.lastName();
  user.age = faker.datatype.number({ min: 1, max: 99 });

  if (contacts) { user.contacts = contacts }

  return user
}

export function createContacts(): UserContacts {
  const contact = new UserContacts()
  contact.email = faker.internet.email();
  contact.phone = faker.phone.phoneNumber('##########');
  contact.address = faker.address.city();

  return contact;
}

async function bootstrap() {
  try {
    const connection = await createConnection();
    const userRepository = connection.getRepository(Users);
    const contactRepository = connection.getRepository(UserContacts);

    const contacts = createContacts();
    const user = createUser(contacts);

    contactRepository.save(contacts);
    userRepository.save(user);

    console.info('Done!');

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}

bootstrap();
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you post your code used for saving ? In your controller and service

Comment: I updated the post. I think I need three save calls because in one save I created contacts without user_id in the second I created a user with contact_id and in third, I should update contacts for updating user_id column. I already tried this variant but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, in fact, regarding to doc (https://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations) you can retreive users from your contacts table without explicit id on both side. You can get user by using contactRepository.find({relations: ["users"]). If you really want to duplicate the id information (that I would not recommand) you'll have to do it manually by updating this user_id column.

Comment: Ahhaha and if I want to find a user via another ORM/Native SQL query what do I need to do?))

Comment: You can do what typeORM do for you, something like : Select * From Users + Join UserContact table on users.contact_id = usercontact.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OneToOne decorator without JoinColumn used by TypeORM as metadata for bi-directional relationship

```js
@Entity()
export class UserContacts {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  contact_id: number;

  // This property is metadata. It's not column for DB
  @OneToOne(_ => Users, users => users.contacts)
  user: Users;
}
```